# JAVA : "java.util.InputMismatchException" error

Tags: java

new programmer here, just trying to finish my programming assignment (last one of the semester)!

Basically, assignment is as follows: Write a program that reads integers, finds the largest of them, and counts its occurrences. Assume the input ends with 0.

My code:
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class IntCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max;
        int count = 1;
        int num;
        int test = 1;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter integers");
        num = scan.nextInt();

        String[] testNums = Integer.toString(num).split("");

        max = Integer.parseInt(testNums[0]);
        System.out.println("TEST MAX = " + max);
        int leng = testNums.length;

        while (leng != 1) {

            if ((Integer.parseInt(testNums[test])) == max) {
            count++;

            }

            if ((Integer.parseInt(testNums[test])) > max) {
            max = Integer.parseInt(testNums[test]);
            }

            leng = leng - 1;
            test = test + 1;

        }

        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(testNums));

        if (leng == 1) {
            System.out.println("Your max number is: " + max);
            System.out.println("The occurances of your max is: "                +count);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your max number is: " + max);
            System.out.println("The occurrences of your max is: " +    count);
        }

    }
}
```

Code will work fine for input such as: 3525550 (max number is 5, occurrences is 4)

Code will not work for input such as: 36542454550
For this iput, I receive the following error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "36542454550"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at IntCount.main(IntCount.java:13)

No idea how to fix this and its driving me nuts!! not looking for direct answer, as I wouldn't learn anything, but maybe some guidance on what to do next. Thank you all ahead of time!

Comment: Side note: Your program doesn't seem to do what the assignment asks for. I believe the assignment requires entering several integers, like 157 (new line) 2987 (new line) 1526 (new line) 2987 (new line) 0 (new line) - and your answer should be 2987 and 2 in this case. The assignment is about *integers*, not *digits*. If it was about digits, you wouldn't need to finish with zero to know it's the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Integers have a max value of `2147483647`. The number in your input bigger. Scan for a `long` instead of `int`.

Alternatively, scan for a `String` (since you're already converting your `Integer` to a string).

Answer (score 0):

`36542454550` is too big of a number to hold in an `int`

Try using `double` or `long`

The max value for a signed integer is 2147483647

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use bigInteger in this kind of situations, you can see more information about bigIntegers here: [BigIntegers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: why use BigInts when a primitive is more than adequate

Comment: I disagree. I believe that the OP did the assignment wrong, but to correct his code for what he's trying to do, his source is reading in an integer, and immediately converting it to a String. I would recommend that he read the input as a String and ignore number parsing altogether.

Comment: when you are working with big numbers, I think it's much much better practise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a program that does what you described:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    SortedMap<Long, Integer>  maxMap = new TreeMap<>();
    Long newLong = null;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please Enter a Integer: ");
        newLong = scan.nextLong();  
        int count = maxMap.containsKey(newLong) ? maxMap.get(newLong) : 0;
        maxMap.put(newLong, ++count);
    } while (newLong.intValue() != 0);

    System.out.println("Max number is: " + maxMap.lastKey());
    System.out.println("Count: " + maxMap.get(maxMap.lastKey()));
    scan.close();
}
```